# I'm getting a math domain error in my Python code and have no clue what to do

Tags: python, josephus

I'm trying to do some code for the Josephus Problem, but I keep getting a weird error. My code looks like this:

```py
import math
power = 2
originalnumber = int(input("how many to start?"))
powerof2 = math.log(originalnumber,power)
if type(powerof2) == int:
    powerof2tf = True
    winningseat = 1
else:
    powerof2tf = False
    newnumber = originalnumber
    while True:
        newnumber = newnumber - 1
        variabletest = type(math.log(newnumber,power))
        if variabletest == int:
            break
        else:
            pass
    winningseat = 1+2*(originalnumber-newnumber)

print("the winning seat is", winningseat)
```

When I try to run it it gives me this error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()

```
 12         import math

 13         newnumber = newnumber - 1
```

---> 14         variabletest = type(math.log(newnumber,power))

```
 15         if variabletest == int:

 16             break
```

ValueError: math domain error

Any ideas? I have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `math.log(0, 2)` is `undefined`.  [Here's](http://www.mclph.umn.edu/mathrefresh/logs3.html) a good site to refresh your knowledge on how `log` works in general math.

> log 0 is undefined. It's not a real number, because you can never get zero by raising anything to the power of anything else. You can never reach zero, you can only approach it using an infinitely large and negative power.

You need to revise your code to handle `newnumber` getting to zero, then this problem will go away.

Comment: newnumber shouldn't ever equal zero, it should get to 1 or 2 at the lowest. At one point (a while ago) it would run but if you put in 10 as originalnumber it woul output 1 even though it should have been 5.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't ever equal zero, but it does, and that's why you're getting the error.  Add `print('newnumber: ' + str(newnumber))` above line 14 and watch the output.  I'm trying to give you hints around your specific problem without solving the problem for you, that's not what SO is here for.

Comment: ah, you're right, it is getting down to zero. for some reason it's not stopping when it reaches a power of 2

Comment: Correct.  You need to look at how you're testing whether you got a good value.  Your line `if variabletest == int` is asking "Is variabletest of Type int?"  But `math.log(...` will never return a `type == int`, so check out some other options for that test.